# Angular Routing Issue: Not Working for 'http://localhost:4200/#access_token=MytokenValue

Tags: angular, angular16

I am getting a route from Third Party app post authentication, Route is like below:
http://localhost:4200/#access_token=dynamicTokenValue

I had configured this route as below when I was using Angular 11 and it was working as expected, Post upgrade to Angular 16, It stopped working.
`{ path: 'access_token', data: { breadcrumb: 'ABC', }, redirectTo: 'mycomp', }`

P.S: I have path configured for 'mycomp' with lazy loading (ESM).

I tried below but did not work for me, It's treating 'access_token=:id' as a string instead of treating :id as dynamic value.

`{ path: 'access_token=:id', data: { breadcrumb: 'ABC', }, redirectTo: 'mycomp', }`

Below are examples:
Working in Angular 11:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angualar-routing-in-angular-demo-example-yz3igv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Working Route: https://angualar-routing-in-angular-demo-example-yz3igv.stackblitz.io/#access_token=2332

Not working in Angular 16:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-erafn2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Not Working Route: https://angular-erafn2.stackblitz.io/#access_token=24224

Comment: Working in Angular 11:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angualar-routing-in-angular-demo-example-yz3igv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Working Route: https://angualar-routing-in-angular-demo-example-yz3igv.stackblitz.io/#access_token=2332

 

 

Not working in Angular 16:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-erafn2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Not Working Route: https://angular-erafn2.stackblitz.io/#access_token=24224

Comment: Can anyone give me a reason why it was working in Angular 11 and not working in Angular 16 ? What change is causing the failure?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this fix

Inside app component ts file:-

```
  ngOnInit() {
    // Check if the 'access_token' query parameter is present in the URL
    const hashURL= location.hash.slice(1);
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(hashURL);

    if (urlParams.has('access_token')) {
      // Redirect to your file
      this.router.navigate(['/mycomp']);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Already tried, But not working. Actually i need to make changes only in routing file or routes to make it working else My token will be no more valid.
Basically wanna know the reason why its not working post upgrade to Angular 16. What's the change ?

Comment: @user3300589 the URL you are hitting is incorrect that's why on angular 16 it is not working.

check this fix now:-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xkvaac?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome-component%2Fhome-component.component.ts